# Finding blocks of C# comments in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

When using the Find command in Visual Studio, what is a regex that can be used to find blocks of comments in C# code (i.e. comments on consecutive lines) e.g.

```
// No need to find single line comment
void Foo()
{
    // I want to find this line.
    // And this line, because they are
    // on consecutive lines
}
```

I sometimes will rework code by commenting out the original version, work on a copy, and then later on coming back and to delete the original commented out code. I'm looking for a regex that will help me to locate the commented out code.

Comment: This is a kind of roll-your-own source control? The better thing to do would be to add `//TODO` comments, which show up in the [Task List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txtwdysk.aspx). You can even make custom task tokens (see link I provided).

Comment: Good idea to use TODO. I use my process built over years of using other editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a starting point. This obviously misses `/* comment */` comments.

```
//.*\r?\n.*//

//               match // literally
.*               match any character 0 to unlimited times
\r?              match a carriage return optionally
\n               match a new line
.*               match any character 0 to unlimited times
//               match // literally
```

If you flag comments with TODO, i.e. `//TODO: Fix this broken thing`, you can easily find them in the task list later (View menu, Task List).

Answer (score 2):

This will do it `[\s\S]([^a-zA-Z/][^\n\r][a-zA-Z/]?//.*[/]*)`

See https://regex101.com/r/wsGNZy/1

Comment: Finds each line seperately, instead of all comment lines en bloc.